# Change font color in table th

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have an html table and I want to style the table font,

```css
table,
thead,
th {
  color: white;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table class="table table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr style="background-color:#3173AD;">
      <th>Action</th>
      <th style="color:white; font-size:10pt;">User Name</th>
      <th style="color:white; font-size:10pt;">User Type</th>
      <th style="color:white; font-size:10pt;">Department</th>
      <th style="color:white; font-size:10pt;">Mobile Number</th>
      <th style="color:white; font-size:10pt;" ng-hide="true"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="data in getdata">
      <td>
        <a href="#" ng-click="update(data)" class="btn btn-warning active fa fa-edit"></a>
        <a href="#" ng-click="delete(data)" class="btn btn-danger active fa fa-remove"></a>
      </td>
      <td>{{data.Username}}</td>
      <td>{{data.usertype}}</td>
      <td>{{data.designation}}</td>
      <td>{{data.mobilenumber}}</td>
      <td ng-hide="true">{{data.userautoid}}</td>
      <td ng-hide="true">{{data.profile}}</td>
      <td ng-hide="true">{{data.picname}}</td>
      <td ng-hide="true">{{data.email}}</td>
      <td ng-hide="true">{{data.hod}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

But the font color of `th` is not changing

The following is what I used, but am unable to change the color

```
<th style="">User Name</th>
```

and this is what I am doing now to fix this

```
<th style="color:white; font-size:10pt;" ng-hide="true"></th>
```

This is working properly but I want to use the css class

What more do I need to do now?

Comment: the definition of css that you put, must work

Comment: It seems to work fine for me: https://jsfiddle.net/rcygmh08/

Comment: It's likely either your CSS file isn't being applied, you've got a rule that's overwriting it (ie an identical selector applied later in your CSS or inline), you've got a more specific rule taking precedence. First It's probably a good idea to apply a class to your table for that particular style so that only the tables you want get styled, then Chrome/Firefox's dev tools can help check which rules are/aren't being applied or if lazy - `color:white !important;` will prob cause it to be applied unless there's another `!important` rule being applied for `color`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your present css changes the font color of th. But it also changes the font color of entire table or thead region.

If your requirement is to change the font colors only for th, then I would prefer the following the css :

```
table thead th { color: white; font-size:10pt; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Another method is here:

Try this:

```css
table#table-custom > thead > tr > th{font-size:25px; background:#3173AD; color:#fff; font-family:arial; padding:5px; text-align:center; vertical-align:center;} 
table#table-custom > tbody > tr > td{font-size:15px; background:orange; color:#fff; font-family:impact; letter-spacing:2px; padding:10px; text-align:center; vertical-align:center;} 
table#table-custom > tbody > tr > td > a{color:#fff;}
```

```html
<table id="table-custom" class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
   <tr>
     <th>Action</th>
     <th>User Name</th>
     <th>User Type</th>
     <th>Department</th>
     <th>Mobile Number</th>
     <th></th>
   </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
   <tr ng-repeat="data in getdata">
     <td>
    <a href="#" ng-click="update(data)" class="btn btn-warning active fa fa-edit">Action</a>
    <a href="#" ng-click="delete(data)" class="btn btn-danger active fa fa-remove">Action</a>
     </td>
     <td>Example</td>
     <td>Example</td>
     <td>Example</td>
     <td>Example</td>
     <td>Example</td>
   </tr>
   <tr ng-repeat="data in getdata">
     <td>
    <a href="#" ng-click="update(data)" class="btn btn-warning active fa fa-edit">Action</a>
    <a href="#" ng-click="delete(data)" class="btn btn-danger active fa fa-remove">Action</a>
     </td>
     <td>Example</td>
     <td>Example</td>
     <td>Example</td>
     <td>Example</td>
     <td>Example</td>
   </tr>
   <tr ng-repeat="data in getdata">
     <td>
    <a href="#" ng-click="update(data)" class="btn btn-warning active fa fa-edit">Action</a>
    <a href="#" ng-click="delete(data)" class="btn btn-danger active fa fa-remove">Action</a>
     </td>
     <td>Example</td>
     <td>Example</td>
     <td>Example</td>
     <td>Example</td>
     <td>Example</td>
   </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Hope this will help you!

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to divide styles for `table` with styles for `th`, because white text in the tbody is invisible, and define additional style for `th`:

```css
table, thead, th {
    border:1px solid black;
}
th {
  color:white;
  font-size:10pt;
}
```

```html
<table class="table table-bordered">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr style="background-color:#3173AD;">
                                        <th>Action</th>
                                        <th>User Name</th>
                                        <th>User Type</th>
                                        <th>Department</th>
                                        <th>Mobile Number</th>
                                        <th ng-hide="true"></th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr ng-repeat="data in getdata">
                                        <td>
                                            <a href="#" ng-click="update(data)" class="btn btn-warning active fa fa-edit"></a>
                                            <a href="#" ng-click="delete(data)" class="btn btn-danger active fa fa-remove"></a>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>{{data.Username}}</td>
                                        <td>{{data.usertype}}</td>
                                        <td>{{data.designation}}</td>
                                        <td>{{data.mobilenumber}}</td>
                                        <td ng-hide="true">{{data.userautoid}}</td>
                                        <td ng-hide="true">{{data.profile}}</td>
                                        <td ng-hide="true">{{data.picname}}</td>
                                        <td ng-hide="true">{{data.email}}</td>
                                        <td ng-hide="true">{{data.hod}}</td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
```